# is projective space a spectral topological space?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

A topological space $X$ is said to be *spectral* if it satisfies all of the following conditions:

1) $X$ is quasicompact and quasiseparated

2) $X$ is sober (over irreducible component has a unique generic point) .

3) $X$ has a basis of quasicompact open subsets

Hochster proved that a spectral space is homeomorphic to the spectrum of a ring, i.e. is affine. So projective space $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ over a field (with the Zariski topology) is not a spectral space. Which one(s) of the above three conditions fails? It seems to me that all three hold... so I am confused about something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Projective space is a spectral space, so it is homeomorphic to the spectrum of a ring. For example, $\mathbb{P}^1$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$, which is the spectrum of $k[x]$. Being homeomorphic is a much weaker condition than being isomorphic as varieties.

Comment: +1. On the other hand, $\mathbb{P}^2$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^2$. I wonder if there's a simple way of presenting an affine scheme which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^2$ (over an algebraically closed field)?

Comment: @AlexKruckman: There is no affine variety that is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^2$, since any two curves in $\mathbb{P}^2$ intersect which is impossible for an affine variety (consider generic parallel hyperplane sections).  So I wouldn't expect there to be anything much simpler than just spelling out Hochster's general argument in this example.